# JCrop + Prevent Click Propagation

Tags: jquery, html, jcrop

I'm using jcrop and attaching it to the last

I also have a click event attached to the first div with id="photoCropContainer"

```
    <div id="photoCropContainer">
      <div id="croppingControls">
        <div id="croppingBackgroundContainer">
          <img src="../../images/cropping-default.jpg" id="croppingBackgroundDefault" alt="Pre Cropping Background Default">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="cropBoxWrapper"><img src="../../images/cropping-default.jpg" id="cropBox" alt="Photo Crop Box"/></div>
    </div>
```

*** The reason for this configuration is to allow a user to click the main div when jcrop isn't loaded and what is showing of this when jcrop is loaded so they can upload and crop a different image.

The only issue I have is when someone uses Jcrop it triggers the first div id="photoCropContainer".

Is there a way I can stop click events propagating from id="cropBox" to id="photoCropContainer"?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you can stop propagation by adding the the stopPropagation event to the click like this:

```
$("#clickyclicky").on('click', function(event){
      event.stopPropagation(); //this should stop the click from propagating.
      //do other stuff here                      
});
```

Comment: notice where the word 'event' is.  Its defined in the () braces near the word function and then called in the body of the function.